# Can't load youtube source in php script.

Tags: php, html, youtube, domdocument

Hello I'm making a php script to extract videos URL from [Youtube](http://youtube.com) result. I have this:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(1);

    function conseguir_codigo_url($url) {
        $dwnld = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($dwnld, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($dwnld, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        //$userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.01; Windows NT 6.0)';
        curl_setopt($dwnld, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
        curl_setopt($dwnld, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $fuente_url = curl_exec($dwnld);
        curl_close($dwnld);
        return $fuente_url;
    }

    function extraer_atributo_elemento($fuente) {
        $file = new DOMDocument;

        if($file->loadHTML($fuente) and $file->validate()){

            echo "DOCUMENTO";

            $file->getElementById("search-results");

        }

     $codigo_url = conseguir_codigo_url("http://www.youtube.com/results?search_sort=video_date_uploaded&uni=3&search_type=videos&search_query=humor");
    extraer_atributo_elemento($codigo_url);
?>
```

The trouble is I can't use `getelementbyid`, I think it's maybe **html5**. Have you a suggestions to solve this. I need parse the source and I don't know **regex** . So domdocument is the only way.

Comment: at first you should consider using SimpleXML http://php.net/manual/de/book.simplexml.php

Comment: This is unlikely to get you anywhere. YouTube go through great lengths to make their content un-downloadable. Either way, you should provide a more specific problem description. What exactly goes wrong?

Comment: secondly you should REALLY use english methods. this would probably help understanding the code much faster!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use `$file->validate()`? If you just want to extract an element by ID, no need to call this. Also, setting `DOMDocument::recover` to `true` before calling `loadHTML` may help to parse broken HTML from the net.